# On remove select2 option trigger ajax remove from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

i am trying to build an crud operation with `php` and `js(ajax)` and i have some filters which user can add more filters to a category works fine on adding operation, but on edit i did with ajax and on click is retriving from databse and fill the inputs but on select2 i retrive data like this:

```
        var main_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({  
          url:"<?php echo $site_url;?>/actions/get_filters.php",  
          method:"POST",  
          data:{main_id:main_id},  
          dataType:"json",  
          success:function(data){
            var fl = [];
            var nr = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, field){
              fl.push(field.fil_opt+","+field.txt_fil);
              nr.push(field.id);
                  
            });

            for (i = 0; i < nr.length; ++i) {
                $('#filters_cat_update > option').each(function() {
                   $(this).attr('data-id', nr[i++]);
                });
            }
            $('#filters_cat_update').val(fl);
            $('#filters_cat_update').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
               
          }  
        });
```

I detect when i remove an option like this:

```
    //remove from edit options
    $('#filters_cat_update').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
        console.log(e.params.args.data.id);
    });
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple custom-select mr-sm-2" name="filters_update[]" multiple="multiple" id="filters_cat_update">
    <?php 
        $sqlf = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM filtre WHERE vizibil=1 ORDER BY pozitie");
        while ($rf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlf)) {?>
             <option data-id="" value="<?=$rf['id'];?>,<?=$rf['nume'];?>"><?=$rf['nume'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

What i want to do is when i click one option for example "color" to go with ajax and delete from table mysql where i have filters saved for each category and remove it.
As you see in my option i have concatenaded id of filter and name of filter coming from another table where user can create filters.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can call you ajax under `$('#filters_cat_update').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {..` . did you tried that ?

Comment: Your solution is getting my value like <option data-id="77" value="3,color">Color</option>. Each option have data-id with his unique id in databse and i want to get somehow data-id value parse into ajax to php to delete from mysql what i removed from select2 input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `data-id` using `$("#filters_cat_update option:selected")` which will give you selected option using this you can use `.attr` and `.val()` to get required values .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$('#filters_cat_update').select2();
$('#filters_cat_update').on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {
  var code = $("#filters_cat_update option:selected").attr('data-id'); //getting id 
  var values = $("#filters_cat_update option:selected").val(); //get values
  var datas = values.split(',');
  var id = datas[0]; //id
  var color = datas[1]; //color
  console.log("id - " + id + " color -  " + color + " data-id -" + code)
//ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: "your url",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: id,
      color: color,
      code :code
    }, //send data  
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("done")

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple custom-select mr-sm-2" name="filters_update[]" multiple="multiple" id="filters_cat_update">

  <option data-id="2" value="1,Color">Color</option>
  <option data-id="7" value="2,Color2">Color2</option>
  <option data-id="77" value="3,Color3">Color3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, i solved by doing this: e.params.data.element.dataset.id;